# cannot install raakt/hpricot gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm absolutely a ruby beginner. I am trying to install raakt. This installation is failing - I think because of a dependency on another gem called hpricot. So I take a step back and try to install hpricot first:

```
install gem hpricot
```

Output as follows:

```
C:\Users\Administrator\source\repos\rss>gem install hpricot
Temporarily enhancing PATH for MSYS/MINGW...
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing hpricot:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/hpricot-0.8.6/ex
t/fast_xs
C:/tools/ruby26/bin/ruby.exe -I C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/2.6.0 -r ./siteconf2019
1204-7324-62if1j.rb extconf.rb
checking for stdio.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/tools/ruby26/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:467:in `try_do': The compiler failed to g
enerate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
        from C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:601:in `try_cpp'
        from C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:1109:in `block in have_heade
r'
        from C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:959:in `block in checking_fo
r'
        from C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:361:in `block (2 levels) in
postpone'
        from C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:331:in `open'
        from C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:361:in `block in postpone'
        from C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:331:in `open'
        from C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:357:in `postpone'
        from C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:958:in `checking_for'
        from C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:1108:in `have_header'
        from extconf.rb:2:in `<main>'

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can
 be found here:

  C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.6.0/hpricot-0.8.6
/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/hpri
cot-0.8.6 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.6
.0/hpricot-0.8.6/gem_make.out

C:\Users\Administrator\source\repos\rss>
```

gem_make.out log:

```
current directory: C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/hpricot-0.8.6/ext/fast_xs
C:/tools/ruby26/bin/ruby.exe -I C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/2.6.0 -r ./siteconf20191204-2592-obt2lm.rb extconf.rb
checking for stdio.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=C:/tools/ruby26/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:467:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:601:in `try_cpp'
    from C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:1109:in `block in have_header'
    from C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:959:in `block in checking_for'
    from C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:361:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
    from C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:331:in `open'
    from C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:361:in `block in postpone'
    from C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:331:in `open'
    from C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:357:in `postpone'
    from C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:958:in `checking_for'
    from C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:1108:in `have_header'
    from extconf.rb:2:in `<main>'

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.6.0/hpricot-0.8.6/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1
```

Can anyone suggest a way I can get this installed or have some trouble-shooting tips?

Log looks like this:

```
"x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -o conftest.exe -IC:/tools/ruby26/include/ruby-2.6.0/x64-mingw32 -IC:/tools/ruby26/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby/backward -IC:/tools/ruby26/include/ruby-2.6.0 -I. -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO=1 -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -O3 -fno-fast-math conftest.c  -L. -LC:/tools/ruby26/lib -L. -pipe -s     -lx64-msvcrt-ruby260  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -liphlpapi -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <winsock2.h>
4: #include <windows.h>
5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
6: {
7:   return 0;
8: }
/* end */
```

Full gemfile

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rake', '10.5.0'
gem 'albacore', '2.3.22'
gem 'business_time', '0.8.0'
gem 'nokogiri'
gem 'octokit', '4.3.0'
#gem 'hpricot'
#gem 'raakt'
```

Comment: Hpricot is an old gem and no longer maintained. You will probably have a lot of problems trying to install it. Switch to Nokogiri instead.

Comment: yes - i discovered that it wasn't maintained any longer as i was looking for a solution. i have nokogiri in my gem file (added to the post) i need raakt, which seems to have a dependency on hpricot. can raakt work with nokogiri? forgive me, i'm new to this world!

Comment: No it can't use Nokogiri as replacement. You need to post the output of both logfiles in your question. There's two of them. The other one is missing.

Comment: thanks for coming back again: extra log added for gem_make.out log:

Comment: Did you install the MSYS DevKit with Ruby?

Comment: i tried `ridk install` but that didn't work - proxy problems. so i got it from here: http://www.msys2.org/

Comment: i downgraded ruby to 1.9.3 and i was able to do everything i wanted. thanks for your time